# LWC Can Variables Be Reset & Further Events Fired After Returning From a Back-Button/PopState

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

I have a requirement where I need to update values in an LWC when returned from a back-button popstate.

E.G.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if(event && event.state) {
        // Process this. resetting here.
        // E.G. if needing to set a product tab as selected based on the selectedproduct in the state... 
        this.productToHighlight = event.state.selectedproduct;
    }

 };
```

Is this possible in an LWC?

Is it possible to send an event from within a window.popstate event also?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: In summary, yes, you can. Where exactly are you stuck? How can we help?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox It just does not seem to function. For example this.productToHighlight does not seem to update the parameter.  I also tried to fire an event just to test if an event could be fired "const popReturnEvent = new CustomEvent('processpop', { bubbles: true}); this.dispatchEvent(popReturnEvent);"  however the event did not seem to fire as I'd thought.  In terms of defining "window.onpopstate = function(event)" I did this in the connectedCallback()   Is this the wrong place to define it also? I had tried to create it as a function of it's own but it would not save correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: When I get home I will write a demo for you to try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this seems to work exactly as advertised. I wrote a simple [`popstate`](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/ZWmsLbQuLnJKDXFDmmcU/src/app.css) demo for you.

---

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  _handler;
  connectedCallback() {
    window.addEventListener(
      'popstate',
      this._handler = (event) => this.handlePopState(event)
    );
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    window.removeEventListener('popstate', this._handler);
  }
  store() {
    let value = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value;
    history.pushState( { value }, "Demo" );
  }
  retrieve() {
    history.back()
  }
  handlePopState(event) {
    let inputElement = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input');
    inputElement.value = event.state?.value;
  }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-input label="Data"></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button-group>
        <lightning-button label="Store" onclick={store}></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button label="Retrieve" onclick={retrieve}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-button-group>
</template>
```

It appears that your problem comes from using the wrong `this`. Typically, this behavior occurs when you bind to the wrong object.

```
// Incorrect
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if(event && event.state) {
        // Process this. resetting here.
        // E.G. if needing to set a product tab as selected based on the selectedproduct in the state... 
        this.productToHighlight = event.state.selectedproduct;
    }

 };
```

---

```
// Correct
window.onpopstate = (event) => {
    if(event && event.state) {
        // Process this. resetting here.
        // E.G. if needing to set a product tab as selected based on the selectedproduct in the state... 
        this.productToHighlight = event.state.selectedproduct;
    }
 };
```

You can read more about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. Changing "window.onpopstate = function(event) {" to "window.onpopstate = (event) => {" has fixed it.  I'll read up on the links you have provided for reference. Thanks a lot. I was unsure if there was a general limitation in relation to it.